# how can i load data when click on tab in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i had created 4 Visualforce tab. and also implement that when user click on the tab at that time only respective page load. and it is working also. but problem is data of default page is loading but the data of included page is not loading with page. i had post my code here. so how can i load data when click on particular tab. ?????![enter image description here][1]

```
            <apex:tab id="tab1" name="tab1" >
               <apex:detail/> 
            </apex:tab>


            <apex:tab id="tab2" name="tab2" >
                <apex:include pageName="page2" />
                </apex:tab>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `<apex:tab>` components in an `<apex:tabpanel>` component, like so:

```
<apex:tabpanel selectedTab="tab1">
  <apex:tab name="tab1">
    <!-- put tab 1 content here -->
  </apex:tab>
  <apex:tab name="tab2">
    <!-- put tab2 content here -->
  </apex:tab>
  <!-- etc -->
</apex:tabpanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Triangle Man  for your response. yes i had wrap <apex:tab> component in an <apex:tabpanel>. But Here issue is like i had included page with respective tab and all page having same standard controller called Account. Now problem is when i click on the tab, the page is loading but it's data is not showing but counting of record is showing. Now when i reload the page then data is showing ( If i Refresh (Using press F5 ) the page at that time data is showing ) so is there any suggestion ????

Comment: @Sandeep_Dobariya From the looks of the code you posted you are using some onclick javascript to load the data that you want to display and using `<apex:include/>` to provide content from other Visualforce pages. A more standard way of doing this would be using a controller extension to provide properties to access the additional data, and using `<apex:component/>` to provide content that is being used in more that one place. I would try rewriting your code in that, more idiomatic way. Let me know if you have questions about how best to do that.